# iPad back button stops working on rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I am developing a iphone/ipad app.

Problem is that when i change the orientation of ipad portrait to Landscape, back button of navigation controller stops working.

It"s work fine when orientation not changed.

i am using this code

```
 - (BOOL) isPad{    
 #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
 #else
    return NO;
 #endif
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
if ([self isPad]) {
    return YES;
}
else 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

}
```

What"s the wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

Now implement the following method :

```
-(void)checkOrientation
{
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{

    // Set x coorinate of views you want to change

}
else
{

    // Set x coordinates of views to initial x xoordinates.

}

}
```

Create recievedRotate :

```
- (void)receivedRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{    
[self checkOrientation];
}
```

In viewDidLoad :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{  
// Code    
[self checkOrientation];
}
```

Comment: That could work, but so could setting the correct AutoResizingMask values on the UIView and its components.. Best is to do this through Interface Builder, but can be set programmatically if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your button is out of the view's frame and thus won't receive touch events. I think something is wrong with the way your app redraws on orientation change.